# Spring security error 403 handling: login page for unauthorized, 403 error for authorized user

Tags: java, spring-security

I have following problem with 403 error handling. This is my configuration:

Part of my spring-security.xml

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="ep403" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login"
                    login-processing-url="/login"
                    username-parameter="email"
                    password-parameter="password"
    />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/errors/access-denied"/>
    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
                logout-success-url="/login"/>
    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession"/>
</sec:http>



<bean id="ep403" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
```

If logged/unauthorized user enter to link without rights to view url - he will be redirected to 403 error page and logged out from system if already logged in. I need solution which allow me to redirect logged user to 403 page & logout, but for unauthorized user i want to see login page instead of 403 error, do You know there's any chance to achieve that goal?

I try with my own AuthenticationEntryPoint implementation, I want to check user from Security Context and if its not logged in - execute different action than redirect to forbidden page, but authentication is always null in this case, because logged user on this error page is unfortunately already logged out

```
public class AccessDeniedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authenticationauthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access Denied");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your /errors/access-denied mapping check for **JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE** cookies. if they are null that means the user had not a successful login to have the cookies, so redirect him to login, if not let him see the access-denied page.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/errors/access-denied")
public String error(HttpServletRequest request) {
  Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
  if (cookies != null) {
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID") || 
            cookie.getName().equals("SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE")) {
            return "access-denied";
        }
    }
  return "login";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your security config file I think you might need to add the url of you application that doesn't need or require Authentication for example .

```
        @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests() 
        .antMatchers("/login*",""
                + "/signin/**",""
                + "/signup/**",""
                + "/api/v1/products/**",""
                + "/api/v1/addproduct/**",""
                + "/api/v1/addCategory/**"
                ).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
//        .and() 
//        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout();
    } // @formatter:on
```